# Angular Library with Ivy enabled fails to load

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-ivy

I am trying to create an angular library project but I am getting this error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34470)
    at core.js:34488
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34484)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:34651)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:40286)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:40609)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
```

I have created a new angular project with `ng new --enable-ivy` then added a library with `ng g library my-lib`. My library has a secondary endpoint with a module (below) so the import would be `import { MyLibModule } from 'my-lib/secondary';`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyLibDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    MyLibDirective
  ]
})
export class MyLibModule {
  public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyLibModule,
      providers: []
    };
  }
}
```

I build this using `ng build my-lib` which all builds fine, and I am using link to include the library in the demo app, in the dist folder for the library I run `yarn link` and in the root demo app folder I run `yarn link my-lib`, then include the module in the imports of the `AppModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyLibModule } from 'my-lib/secondary';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyLibModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However when I run `yarn start` or `ng serve` everything builds fine but I get the above error in the console, debugging this in the browser it would appear that the `ngModuleDef` property in my library module does not exist, does anyone know why this happens?

NOTE: This is not a problem if I turn Ivy off but with ng9 coming soon this is not really a viable solution and I would like to know what I have done wrong (if anything) with the library

Output from `ng version`

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 12.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.21
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.21
@angular/cli                       8.3.21
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.21
@schematics/angular                8.3.21
@schematics/update                 0.803.21
ng-packagr                         5.7.1
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: @NeilStevens i don't know where the error comes from, but angular advises not to generate/publish an ivy library yet [read here](https://next.angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility). To maintain backwards compatibility

Comment: @Reactgular update question

Comment: @PierreDuc I am not generating an ivy library I am using the View Engine compiler for the library, `ngcc` gets used on the library when I build/serve the demo app

Comment: @NeilStevens ah alright, I get it now. Mm, feels like something goes wrong when importing a src library like that. What happens if you use the relative path while importing it? Like `../../projects/my-lib/lib/src/my-lib.module`? Or what happens if you change the return type of the forRoot() with `ModuleWithProviders<MyLibModule>`

Comment: @PierreDuc changing the return type made no difference, importing directly from the source works but that kinda defeats the purpose of a library

Comment: @NeilStevens Obviously :) but at least we're closer to the answer now. Can you share the paths in tsconfig.json? And you are saying it does run the ngcc command on your library, right? And no errors or warnings coming from that?

Comment: Also, you are using opt-in stuff though. With the beta and rc version from angular 9, a lot of fixes have been done in both the angular core and the cli. So I can imagine you are just running into one of the bugs they've fixed. Is it possible for you to update to angular 9 already?

Comment: @PierreDuc I am not using `paths` from tsconfig, I have a library on npm which I have installed on a brand new project with ivy enabled, then using `yarn link` on the library

Comment: Not possible to upgrade the main project to ng9 yet but I will try with the demo app to see if that resolves this problem

Comment: @NeilStevens Mm, the angular cli should create paths automatically in your tsconfig.json pointing to the dist lib. I don't think you should be using yarn link. About the other thing, more people have this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31314) and they advice to update to angular 9

Comment: 99% of everything I do these days is in an Angular library. I've avoid Ivy like the plague, because it constantly gave me problems with libraries. Even updates to Angular 8 that bring forward support for Ivy have broken my libraries. I really hope Angular 9 isn't going to be a huge breaking update, because Ivy looks very promising and I've seen some cool stuff done with it. Like support for custom decorators on bindings. There is more going on there then just performance improvements. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @PierreDuc I had seen that issue but dismissed it as I was not using the browser animation module but `ng update @angular/cli --next` has resolved this problem, the issue is I cannot upgrade my project yet but would like to get the benefits of Ivy

Comment: @NeilStevens try adding `"preserveSymlinks": true` in `architect.build.options` of `angular.json` in your application that uses angular package.

Had similar issue (although different error message) when linking angular package in ivy enabled v8 app (it was working fine with ivy disabled).

Answer (score 0):

1. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.19 --check your project CLI version
   3.ng_Modules delete  from the local folder
3. npm install